# How to set the returnKeyType of TextInput in qt5.6 qml

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, textinput

I [saw](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-enterkey.html) Qt added the `EnterKey` QML type at v5.6, but how to use it in a `TextInput`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import QtQuick 2.6

TextInput {
    EnterKey.type: Qt.EnterKeyNext
}
```

Comment: for some reason on QtQuick 2.11 this doesn't work. It says "Non-existent attached object"

Comment: same for me. Non-existent attached object. Tried 2.6, 2.15... no luck. using PySide6